# In what file is the WiFi connection chosen in the GUI persisted?

Tags: wifi, configuration, wifi-hotspot

I am asking this question about several different linux systems:

1. Ubuntu
2. Raspbian
3. Arch Linux

Each of these systems offers a GUI with a list of Wifi servers in which you pick the one you wish to connect to.  I would like to know, for each of these, where this choice is persisted, so that it's available the next time you connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For systems using NetworkManager (which includes all of the above distributions, at least in common configurations), the location is typically `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`; e.g:

```
$ ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
Starbucks.nmconnection
Company Wifi.nmconnection
```

Where the files look something like:

```
[connection]
id=Company WIFI
uuid=12345678-5e72-456a-a46d-7cb239f2d5de
type=wifi
interface-name=wlan0

[wifi]
mode=infrastructure
ssid=Company WIFI

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=secretpassword

[ipv4]
method=auto

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=default
method=auto

[proxy]
```

NetworkManager will iterate through available Wifi connection profiles until it finds one that works.

Comment: Thanks, @larsks, Yes, I found this to be the case.  I also found that these systems also offer the nm-connection-editor program which provide a front-end for changing these files. Importantly, this does not happen in real time. It's just editing a file which will be read at the next boot. If you are accessing the system over a noVNC connection, and try to change the network with the GUI, then you kill the session.